# Why method call on class level always expect static parameter?

Tags: c#

I have just written following two lines and got following error

**Error**

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property
```

**Code**

```
class Sample
{
   public string number = "13";
   public int a = int.Parse(number);
}
```

Yes, I know if I declare string as static then problem will go away. But I am not getting why it is occurring.

Comment: Did you run your code? the actual error is: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`. Not a real question.

Comment: SMI, I've edited your code to match your error, please for future questions make sure to provide samples that match question. If you feel that this edit is wrong - revert, but make sure to fix you post. Also avoid thank you notes of any kind. Showing effort (like reading MSDN about particular error code or searching for error http://www.bing.com/search?q=A+field+initializer+cannot+reference+the+non-static+field%2C+method%2C+or+property is much better than "thank you help me."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't "expect static" *anything* - simply: you aren't allowed to access `this` at this point, and `number` is implicitly `this.number`. Move the code to a constructor instead:

```
public Foo()
{
    number = "13";
    a = Convert.ToString(number);
}
string number;
int a;
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(aStringCalledNumber)`?

Comment: @spender my code was based on the now-edited code in the original question